# How can I simplify this design to make it a two-color object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, layers

I purchased a vector file from a stock vector website, thinking it would be easy to edit.

However, when I opened it, the layers were a mess.

[image]

I would like it to be just two objects - a white vector object and a blue vector object, without any clipping masks or hidden layers.

My goal is to use either the left or the right side or both sides of the image as a transparent vector image over a background, spaced out to have elements in the middle.

### Is there a simple way to do this in Illustrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select All
- Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**

If you want just white and blue objects, you're done at this point. But... if you want just blue objects continue... (I would want just blue.. then I can manually add a simple white rectangle behind the blue if necessary.)

- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White Arrrow) to click a white object
- Choose  `Select > Same > Fill and Stroke`
- Hit the <kbd>Delete Key</kbd>

You'll be left with some minor issues which you'll have to manually correct. Random paths which join pieces causing a sliver of blue to show. This is due to original construction and slight misalignment of some objects. See below...

[image]

<sub>(Note file is generated by some bleeding-edge version of Illustrator. I can't open the original file here. Opened in Acrobat, saved as PDF then opened that PDF in AICS6 and AICC2017. Not sure why anyone saves an *EPS* as the bleeding-edge version.  `:)` )</sub>

Comment: Muh. The point of .eps files is to be compatible with software from the Stone Age -- no edge needed there, let alone a bleeding one. ^^

Comment: @Vincent that's kind of my thought too.. AI EPS hasn't changed since v10 (I think).

Comment: Thanks @Scott - sorry about how illustrator exported the EPS. The first part of the question was what I'm trying to achieve - the two patterns are different so using them to frame an element in a composition is better done with the white shape on one side and blue on another otherwise it looks mirrored. Anyways - thanks

Comment: @MicroMachine I would do the above to get only blue.... clean it up. Draw a white rectangle behind, select all and *then* use Pathfinder > Merge again to generate the white. Cleaner end result beach you'll only need to fix those minute issues once.